# browsing Istio/k8s services from internet

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have started to read Istio-in-action (by Manning) and Mastering-service-mesh (by Packt) and there are some examples where I cannot 'see' the right output.
I work on my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 and I use [kind] for my local k8s cluster where I can  create 3 or more worker-nodes.

When I deploy some Istio resources (e.g. virtual service) I would like to browse the service-mesh from my Ubuntu browser or from a different client (either a different laptop or cell phone) but it misses something in my 'infrastructure'- is it the external load balancer or some local Ubuntu configuration? Is it mandatory to work with a public cloud provider - GCP/AWS/Azure ; if Yes, which one is the most simple? I have tried with `kubectl port-forward` but without success.

Other resources are ok (e.g. istioctl dashboard kiali/jaeger/prometheus) even without an ExternalIP.

Could you help me to find a blog or a tutorial/hint/advice about the necessary elements for browsing the k8s/Istio services from the internet?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly did you try? Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: I have deployed the samples/bookinfo services and following the examples from the book(s). For some of them the External-IP seems to be a mandatory condition and I was looking for some alternatives. I am adding below the versions: 
i) kubectl version Client Version: :"v1.22.2", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server Version: "v1.21.1", , Platform:"linux/amd64"} 

ii) kind version
kind v0.11.1 go1.16.4 linux/amd64


iii)istioctl version
client version: 1.11.2
control plane version: 1.11.2
data plane version: 1.11.2 (8 proxies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing istio with the istio-ingressgateway enabled a service with that name is created in the `istio-system` namespace.

```
❯ kubectl get svc -n istio-system
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   100.71.98.21     <pending>     80:32564:80/TCP,...
```

When deploying istio to a public cloud provider, that will create a load balancer (like AWS ELB) for you. When the setup is done the `EXTERNAL-IP` will switch from `<pending>` to an actual ip, the public ip of the load balancer. You can access your cluster by visiting that ip.

On your local setup you don't have this luxury. But the service still is created. In the `PORT(S)` column you can see a bunch of ports. That is actually a port mapping. So ports of your node machine are being mapped to that service.

You use this to get the port mapped to http (port 80): For me it would be the `32564`. Or you can run this:

```sh
kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].nodePort}'
```

Now just open your browser and use one of your worker's ip to access the cluster by visiting `<NODE_IP>:<PORT>` (where `PORT` is the one from above).

See [docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/)